# Riley's Imposter!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

#### Here is a six-letter word: `######`

- `si####`: I am the result of heat.
- `##dd##`: I am the result of a depression.
- `####le`: I am the result of laziness.

#### What is `######`?

---

#### Rules:

Instead of giving you a hint for each of the prefix, infix and suffix of the word to figure out the word, I will give you an *imposter* prefix, infix and suffix.

Each imposter will be masked onto the hidden word one by one, and I will give you a hint for each of what the resulting words are.

For example, if my word is `cat`, the riddle might go something like:

- `r##`: I like cheese. *("cat" with an imposter prefix of "r" results in "rat".)*
- `#u#`: I split things. *("cat" with an imposter infix of "u" results in "cut".)*
- `##r`: I need gas. *("cat" with an imposter suffix of "r" results in "car".)*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the answer might (rather appropriately) be:

> **PUZZLE** (yes, I've seen the third line - bear with me...)

`si####`: *I am the result of heat.*

> Changing **PU** to SI makes **SIZZLE**, a noise made when something is *hot* (e.g. when cooking).

`##dd##`: *I am the result of a depression.*

> Changing **ZZ** to DD makes **PUDDLE**, something which forms in a *depression* on the ground when water gathers in it.

`####le`: *I am the result of laziness.*

> Here, the OP is being crafty! Out of *laziness* they have decided to use the same two letters here as in the actual word we are trying to find! Thus **LE** is not actually replaced at all!

Comment: If `####le` means not replaced, what about `sizzle`, `fuddle`, `fuzzle`?

Comment: @tsh We go for common words, for example, words that are defined here: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/spellcheck/english According to the dictionary, fuddle and fuzzle don't qualify. Just looking at this comment as it's being typed, there's a squiggly red line under those two words.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative point of view:

> **FICKLY**

`si####`: *I am the result of heat.*

> (**FI**CKLY -> **SI**CKLY) People feel sickly if they stay long in too warm place.

`##dd##`: *I am the result of a depression.*

> (FI**CK**LY -> FI**DD**LY) People feel fiddly as a result of depression.

`####le`: *I am the result of laziness.*

> (FICK**LY** -> FICK**LE**) Unreliability is a result of lazyness.