# Another Riley's Imposter!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I could not `contain` my enthusiasm for this new style of puzzle! Let's see if I've got what it takes.

#### Here is a seven-letter word: `#######`

- `co#####`: describes this puzzle because it's made up of many pieces.
- `##nta##`: doesn't describe this puzzle, but maybe years from now it will.
- `#####in`: might describe this puzzle, because all puzzles are a bit evil.

What is `#######`?

---

#### Rules:

This is another puzzle in the genre of [@ention everyone's puzzle from yesterday](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105112). The rules are the same, and I've quoted them below.

> Instead of giving you a hint for each of the prefix, infix and suffix
> of the word to figure out the word, I will give you an *imposter*
> prefix, infix and suffix.
>
> Each imposter will be masked onto the hidden word one by one, and I
> will give you a hint for each of what the resulting words are.
>
> For example, if my word is `cat`, the riddle might go something like:
>
> - `r##`: I like cheese. *("cat" with an imposter prefix of "r" results in "rat".)*
> - `#u#`: I split things. *("cat" with an imposter infix of "u" results in "cut".)*
> - `##r`: I need gas. *("cat" with an imposter suffix of "r" results in "car".)*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> village

> collage: a collection of many pieces

> vintage: old, but not in a bad way

> villain: a real moustache-twirler

Comment: Very nice, and very quick!